# Android M shortcut install/uninstall duplication

Tags: android, android-intent, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am trying to create a shortcut for my application through a service.
The following code is working on `SDK <= 21`, but its not working correctly on `SDK = 23`

The creation of the shortcut is done this way:

```
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHORTCUT_CLICKED, true); //This is only to check when the user clicked on the created shortcut
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "TEST");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.application_icon));
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);

        sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

In `SDK <= 21` the shortcut is created and if already exists it will not create other instance.

In `SDK = 23` the shortcut will only be duplicated if I press the created shorcut and try to create the shortcut again, or If I reboot the device and then try to create the shortcut again.

I tried to uninstall the shortcut first but without success on `SDK 23`, as follows:

```
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_SHORTCUT_CLICKED, true); //This is only to check when the user clicked on the created shortcut
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "TEST");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(context, R.drawable.application_icon));
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);

        sendBroadcast(addIntent);
```

This is the service implementation:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

 @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        createShortcut(); //This is where I create the shortcut
        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
    }
}
```

Did Android 6 changed the shortcut creation politics? I cannot find anything on the documentation.

[**UPDATE**] I tried to make this shortcut creation by clicking on a button on a sample application and this still happens. The shorcut will duplicate once I click on the created shortcut and then try to create it again. Same thing happens rebooting the device.

[**UPDATE2**] I was looking on the grep code for the Launcher3 google application and I found that the shortcut installation calls the [registerSessionCallback](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.java#PackageInstaller.registerSessionCallback%28android.content.pm.PackageInstaller.SessionCallback%2Candroid.os.Handler%29) which depends on the calling thread. Might be an issue regarding these new changes?

Comment: You should also note that the broadcast you were using is internal, it's not publicly documented thus it applies only to that specific launcher. From my experience other launchers don't (always) follow the google launcher convention.

Comment: You are right, this is very unreliable, although this was the only way to create shorcuts in almost all devices without duplicating the shortcut, until now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For people who got stuck with the same issue:

Google removed support of Uninstall shortcut on Launcher3 and Google now Launcher on Android M.

Additionally, the duplication of shortcuts is an issue on the lastest Android M build (MRA58K) and its now on the development team hands.

You guys can follow the issue here, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=179697

[**UPDATE**] Google has just fixed the issue and it will be released on the next version.

Comment: I also did not found any documentation about that, but is also normal, because installing and uninstalling shorcuts were never fully supported by android API. 
Although PM amruthav said: "We've completely removed support for the UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT intent in AOSP Launcher3 and Google Now Launcher. Currently there is no alternative or replacement for this API."

I also tested this, and on android M that is not possible anymore the same way I was doing it on previous android versions.

Comment: This also applies if you download the Google Launcher directly from the playstore!

Comment: That's correct because google launcher shares the same code as launcher 3 provided by android OS

Comment: Take a look here, for some reason they've removed the listener for the Uninstall but kept the Install listener... 
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Launcher3/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is helpful for some of you. While Google removed the support
for the uninstall of a shortcut, a shortcut, that points to an activity-alias
will still get removed, once the alias is disabled. ;)

Comment: Well I think it is clear enough what my statement is about and you should be able to do the further research yourself. I won't explain here in detail what an activity alias is or that a shortcut has to point to some sort of activity or alias. But just in case: Your shortcut intent has to start the alias, not an activity. The alias will redirect to your original activity. And once you disable the alias, the shortcut will get removed, too.

Comment: I just noticed that my comment sounds a bit ranting. Sorry for that. If you ask a specific question, then I will update my answer. I just don't want to provide a complete code example, because there are many code examples for the two steps needed out there.